# Is there a standard way of configuring a mapping from model field names to JSON keys on Django Rest Framework?

Tags: json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a Django backend with conventional snake_case model fields. In the frontend, however, they expect another notation. Is there a simple way of configuring a serializer so that every field (e.g. `field_name`) gets automatically converted to the frontend notation (e.g. `fieldName` or even something completely different)? I couldn't find any simple way of doing this. I know I can manually declare each field and use `source`, but besides being a lot of extra work, it still only works for readonly fields if I remember correctly. Besides, it also forces me to declare fields like `fieldName = serializers.CharField(source="field_name", ...)`, and it makes it impossible to use keys like `field-name` in the frontend. Is there any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a render or a parser in DRF to achieve this behavior. There is a [package](https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case) you can use to do that without changing your serializer. `pip install djangorestframework-camel-case`